# Clear terminal up until point x - Python

Tags: python, terminal

A program I'm writing takes user commands from `input()`, executes corresponding functions, and displays relevant text.

[image]

After about 5 commands-worth of text, the terminal becomes cluttered even when the window is maximized. What I would like to do is clear the terminal after every five commands, but only clear the text that precedes (is above) the fifth command and its output text.

More specifically, after the user has typed in the fifth command, upon pressing Return (entering the command), I want commands 1-4 and their corresponding outputs to clear off the screen but have command 5 and its output remain at the top of the terminal.

For demonstration, here is what I want the screen would look like during this process:

[image]

The above becomes the below:

[image]

Using the `os` module and `os.system('cls')` or `os.system('clear')` functions will not exactly work in this situation. I don't want to clear all of the text on the screen, just the text before a certain point.

So, how can I do this on Windows with Python?

Note: If the solutions are simple, I would like both a method of obliterating the text so that it cannot be scrolled back up to as well as a method that would allow users to see previous commands and text.

Comment: Why not clear the screen with `os.system("cls")` or whatever, and then `print "> " + command`, followed by the usual command output?

Comment: @GregHewgill I thought there might be a cleaner alternative I didn't know about. I had considered what you suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using simple terminal output, there isn't really a good way to do this. Even the operation of "clearing the screen" is outside what is normally considered simple terminal output, which is why you end up calling an external program to do it.

However, a different way of handling terminal output is to use the [`curses`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html) library. This library allows you extensive control over exactly how your output appears on the screen, and in fact includes functions like [`deleteln`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.deleteln) and [`insdelln`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.insdelln) to delete lines of text from the screen.